# Python Filtering 2 Lists

Tags: python, list, filter, element

I'm trying to find a way to use one list to filter out elements of another.

Kinda like the intersect syntax but the exact opposite

```
lst = [0,1,2,6]

secondlst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

expected outcome

```
[3,4,5]
```

Comment: The answers using `set` assume that all the items of secondlst are unique and hashable and that their order in the result does not need to be preserved

Comment: @gnibbler however, the `set` solutions will be considerably more performant for large data-sets in those cases, in general.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple way:

```
r = [v for v in secondlst if v not in lst]
```

or

```
list(set(secondlst).difference(lst))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter`

```
filter(lambda x: x not in lst, secondlst)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look no further than Python's [set()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set)' type.

```
>>> lst = [0,1,2,6]
>>> secondlst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> set(lst).symmetric_difference(set(secondlst))
set([3, 4, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
outcome = [x for x in secondlst if x not in lst]
```

More complex but faster if lst is large:

```
lstSet = set(lst)
outcome = [x for x in secondlst if x not in lstSet]
```